# Update Coral Project Code of Conduct link in our CoC page

Tags: discussion, bug, code-of-conduct

At the end of our [Code of Conduct page](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), we have following line:

> This text incorporates ideas and language from the [Coral Project](https://coralproject.net/code-of-conduct/) and [Buffer](https://open.buffer.com/code-of-conduct/) codes of conduct.

I would link to point out that the link for Coral Project CoC i.e `https://coralproject.net/code-of-conduct/` is no longer accessible. Since the CoC moved to another domain, current link redirects to the home page of Coral Project.

[Coral has changed/relaunched as Vox Media](https://www.voxmedia.com/2019/9/10/20857471/coral-vox-media-relaunch), hence the  [Acceptable Use Policy  page](https://coralproject.net/acceptable-use-policy/) on *of Coral Project* stats:

> All Publishers are expected to abide by the [**Vox Media Code of Conduct**](https://code-of-conduct.voxmedia.com/). Failure to abide by the Code of Conduct or these guidelines may result in suspension of publication privileges or termination of accounts.

So, I think we should **update the link** from **`https://coralproject.net/code-of-conduct/`** to **`https://code-of-conduct.voxmedia.com/`**

<sup>Note that I found sometimes `http://` doesn't work for me whereas `https://` works fine.</sup>